# How do I protect a crevice from pests?

Tags: pest-control

I'm furnishing a new room in an apartment. When my landlord remodeled this apartment, he created a nook in the wall, 20cm wide and 34cm deep, starting from waist height and going all the way up to the ceiling. It's a nice little storage space with shelves that you can use to store books and such.

Unfortunately, I want to place a closet on that wall, making that nook inaccessible. I'm okay with losing the storage space in the nook.

I'm worried that because it's an empty space that's almost completely enclosed but not quite. It's hard to reach except from the top of closet. **I'm worried that pests (bugs or rodents) will hide there.**

Is this a reasonable concern? What can I do to prevent that? Do I need to use some filler material? Which kind?

Comment: By saying place a closet there, you mean a premade closet?  If so just cut out the back wall of closet to match the nook.  Then you have the closet plus the nook space to use.  Could also add a small door to the back of closet, so the nook becomes a hidely hole.

Comment: I considered doing that, and I might. I'll get a better idea after the closet is delivered and I start occupying the room. But I also want to have a solution in case I don't go that route. And generally, this seems like a useful thing to know.

Comment: In any building there are many empty spaces that are hidden.  All the walls and ceilings have empty spaces that you can't see in usually.  One little nook will not make much difference.  Would not worry about it unless you hide food in there.

Comment: @crip659 What tool would you use to cut the back of the closet?

Comment: Measuring tape to measure trice, and almost any cutting type saw.  A jig saw would probably be nice, a circuital saw can be used also.